# Rails 3 - Create a button/link to send emails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, email

In my app I have a method that collect all the `Projects` I have in an Array and using `each` I show a link to the user that is accessing, a link to this project.

Well, what I want to do is create a button or a link besides this link to the project that enables me to send an email to the project owner. Working on this for a while and with some help here I discovered that I need to create a method in my `Projects` controller to call the method in my Mailer.

But I think that the way things are going probably won't work, so what would be the right and best way to do this: a link or a button to email the project besides it?

Here is what I have done so far:

I created a method inside my `Projects` controller:

```
def send_email(email, name)
    ProfileMailer.member_alert(email, name).deliver
    #redirect_to :root
end
```

And on my view:

```
<td><%= link_to "Send Email", send_email_projects_path(project.user.email, project.user.name) %></td>
```

Also added a route:

```
resources :projects do
  collection do
    post "send_email"
  end
end
```

And on my `ProfileMailer`

```
  def member_alert(email, name)
    @email = email
    @name = name
    mail(:to => @email, :subject => "#{@name}")
  end
```

With that I will probably have to create a new view page for each email commands I want to insert, and I will have probably more to come so that's why I think this isn't the best way.

Comment: I didn't even know you could generate a route to a mailer--where is that documented? I've always just had an action that sent the email.

Comment: As I said I was a little bit confused and trying many things. But I guess I took the right route now, even thought I get the error I mentioned. Check Edited.

Comment: How does that even render? Shouldn't a link go to an action?

Comment: Actually the error happens when I access the `project#show` now. Using a link or a button the result is the same.

Comment: Because you can't link to a mailer--it doesn't make any sense. Web browsers link to web pages. Link to an action that creates and sends the email.

Comment: So I would have to create another method in, for example, my `ProfileMailer` that calls the `deliver` action and just that?

Comment: Not in the mailer--an action in a cotnroller--see the link provided by Mike.

Answer (score -1):

Luke, you are setting about this completely the wrong way.

You'll normally render a form via a standard controller.  On form submit, the create action will trigger the sending of the email.  I suggest you read up [how ActionMailer works](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#sending-emails) from 2.0 to 2.1.4; the entire process is detailed there in full.

It is also typically advised to make your mailers DB backed, but you can also drop in ActiveModel etc. and send mail without any details being saved to your DB.

The only extra step is thinking about scaling your application if you plan on sending a lot of mail  (i.e. Resque, beanstalkd etc.)

Comment: So been direct: How can I create a link to send an email in any place I want?

Comment: Let's say you've got a ContactUsController.  Your link_to will point to whatever route you've setup pointing to contact_us#new (You can do `rake routes` to see all your routes).  The #new action will render a form; the create action will most likely include `ProfileMailer.member_alert(@email, @name).deliver` (notice the instance variables).

Comment: I will edit once again and show how I am doing cuz I still getting errors.

Comment: I don't know if I expressed myself well but I don't want to create anything new and send emails for example. I have a method that gets all the projects from an Array and I want to add a link to email each project.

Comment: Sounds like you haven't read the documentation I linked you to - also you need to review how MVC works.  If you want to me to fully explain this to you, drop me an email (mike at bsodmike dot com).